# Sufficient conditions for measurability: a collection of distributions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be the underlying probability space. Suppose we have a collection of probability density functions $F(\cdot;x)$ parameterized by $x\in[0,1]$.

Let $X$ be a random variable measurable on probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$. Consider the random variable $Y$ that is distributed according to $F(\cdot;x)$, when $X=x$.

In general, $Y$ need not be measurable on $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$. I am reading a paper which assumes that $\{F(\cdot;x)\}_{x\in[0,1]}$ is such that $Y$ is measurable on the aforementioned probability space.

My question is, whether it is fine to directly make such an assumption on the collection $\{F(\cdot;x)\}_{x\in[0,1]}$. Also, what are the sufficient conditions on $\{F(\cdot;x)\}_{x\in[0,1]}$ that would guarantee measurability?

Comment: Just checking notation: $F$ is usually used for a cumulative distribution function, not a density - are you sure you mean a density here?  Anyway, I suspect you'll want something like for $F : \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ to be jointly Borel.

Comment: Thanks Nate! It is bad notation, but the paper assumes it is a density. Do you think it is fine to make an assumption of measurability directly on $Y$?

Comment: Hm. What does it mean that $Y$ is measurable on $\Omega$? If $\Omega$ contains a single point, then there will be simply no such random variable $Y$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is it fine".  People can assume whatever they want - what's your concern?

Comment: @Ozzy: Are you sure that the paper is reliable/reputable? Can you tell a little bit more about this paper. I think, it has not been published?